# How do include the upper limit of `rand` in Clojure?

Tags: random, clojure

In Clojure's `rand` function, the lower limit 0 is included, but the upper limit is not.
How to define a `rand` function equivalent which includes the upper limit?

Comment: The probability of rand returning *exactly* any given number is extremely small. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @SteffanWestcott it is not a problem in real life but I aske myself - how to make it possible that both limits are inclusive for `rand` ...

Comment: and you are right - the probablity is anyway small ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit (simple explanation):** Because `rand` generates a random double between 0 and 1 by generating an integer and dividing my another integer, you can implement a version with inclusive upper bound as

```clj
(defn rand-with-nbits [nbits]
  (let [m (bit-shift-left 1 nbits)]
    (/ (double (rand-int m))
       (double (dec m)))))

(apply max (repeatedly 1000 #(rand-with-nbits 3)))
;; => 1.0
```

In the implementation, 53 bits are used, that is `(rand-with-nbits 53)`.

**Longer answer:**

Take a look at the [source code of rand](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4941). It internally calls [Math.random](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java#l772), which in turn calls [Random.nextDouble](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Random.java#l531), that has the following implementation:

```java
private static final double DOUBLE_UNIT = 0x1.0p-53; // 1.0 / (1L << 53)
...
public double nextDouble() {
    return (((long)(next(26)) << 27) + next(27)) * DOUBLE_UNIT;
}
```

The above code essentially produces a random integer between `0` and `2^53-1` and divides it by by `2^53`. To get an inclusive upper bound, you would instead have to divide it by `2^53-1`. The above code calls the `next` method which is protected, so to make our own tweaked implementation, we use `proxy`:

```clj
(defn make-inclusive-rand [lbits rbits]
  (let [denom (double
               (dec           ; <-- `dec` makes upper bound inclusive
                (bit-shift-left
                 1 (+ lbits rbits))))
        g (proxy [java.util.Random] []
            (nextDouble []
              (/ (+ (bit-shift-left
                     (proxy-super next lbits) rbits)
                    (proxy-super next rbits))
                 denom)))]
    (fn [] (.nextDouble g))))

(def my-rand (make-inclusive-rand 26 27))
```

It is unlikely that you will ever generate the upper bound:

```clj
(apply max (repeatedly 10000000 my-rand))
;; => 0.9999999980774417
```

However, if the underlying integers are generated with *fewer bits*, you will see that it works:

```clj
(def rand4 (make-inclusive-rand 2 2))

(apply max (repeatedly 100 rand4))
;; => 1.0
```

By the way, the above implementation is **not thread-safe**.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! Would it be possible also to multiply the rand num with `2^53` and then divide it by `2^53-1`? but yeah perhaps not the best performance ...

Comment: How about: `(def ratio (/ (Math/pow 2 53) (- (Math/pow 2 53) 1)))` and then: `(defn myrand [] (* (rand) ratio))`? - inspired by your explanation.

Comment: Would that be a thread-safe version of your `my-rand`?

Comment: Yes, actually, see updated answer. Silly I did not think about that at first.

Comment: Cool! That is now even more elegant!